# Determinant of matrix on wedge product of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, exterior-algebra

Let $T : V \to V$ be a linear map (matrix) on a vector space $V$, and let $V \wedge V$ be the second exterior power of the vector space. Let $e_1, \dots, e_n$ be an orthonormal basis for $V$. Consider the map $e_k \wedge e_j  \mapsto e_k \wedge T e_j + e_j \wedge T e_k$. I want to find the determinant of this map $V \wedge V \to V \wedge V$. Is there an easy way to do this? It may simplify things to assume $T$ is upper triangular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $T$ is diagonal. Notice that if $T$ has two equal eigenvalues, then $e_k\wedge e_j \to 0,$ so the determinant is zero. This suggests that the determinant of your map is the discriminant of the characteristic polynomial of $T.$

Comment: Yes you are right about it being the discriminant, if it is diagonal then it is the vandermonde determinant. And if it is upper triangular I believe (though cannot show) you again get the vandermonde. However I am struggling to show this.

Comment: On further reflection, since the determinant is basis independent you can change to the basis of eigenvectors and what you have said constitutes on a proof. Thank you.